# multiple images uploading issuse

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i am so tired i am trying to upload multiple images but these code insert single image in my database please any body help me what is wrong in my code thanks advance
**my controlle**

```
function blog_img(){
    $this->load->library('upload');

    $files = $_FILES;
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    // Faking upload calls to $_FILE
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) :
      $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $_FILES['userfile']['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $_FILES['userfile']['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $_FILES['userfile']['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $_FILES['userfile']['size'][$i];

      $config = array(
        //'file_name'     => <your ouw function to generate random names>,
        'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
        'max_size'      => 3000,
        'overwrite'     => FALSE,

        /* real path to upload folder ALWAYS */
        'upload_path'
            => './photo/uploads',
      );

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');

    $file_name[] = $this->upload->data();

    $data = array(

        'userfile'   => $this->upload->data('file_name'),

    );

    $this->blog->blog_img($data);
            redirect('/admin/blog/img/new');
    endfor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Here is the solution 

function blog_img(){

    $number_of_file = sizeof($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
    $file = $_FILES['userfile'];

    // Faking upload calls to $_FILE
    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_file; $i++) :

      $_FILES['userfile']['name']     = $file ['name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['type']     = $file ['type'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $file ['tmp_name'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['error']    = $file ['error'][$i];
      $_FILES['userfile']['size']     = $file ['size'][$i];

     $config['upload_path'] = './photo/uploads'; //The path where the image will be save
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
   $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $this->upload->initialize($config);
    $this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $file_name[] = $this->upload->data();
    $data = array(

        'userfile'   => $this->upload->data('file_name'),

    );

    $this->blog->blog_img($data);
    //redirect('/admin/blog/img/new');
    endfor;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just made a mistake,

Just remove `userfile` as below:

```
$this->upload->do_upload();
```

Instead of

```
$this->upload->do_upload('userfile');
```

Use the library `$this->load->library('upload');` before the start of the code.

Make sure your `html` should be like

```
<input type="file" name="userfile[]" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: Virb@ i remove userfile they but only single image is insert in database

Comment: @abbasshah : Which error you are getting then? Have you called `$this->load->library('upload');` at start of the code?

Comment: there is no showing error i select multiple images then submit insert only single image in database i am not sure what  i am going wrong

Comment: See my updated answer that may find the clue where you are going wrong.

Comment: i use the library at top

Comment: <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="userfile[]" id="userfile">

Comment: `$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());` Check with this what you are getting error while uploading.